# Python 2.7 split and .col concatenate

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 version.

I am trying to extract array column name using python.

Array column is mentioned below:

```
`col` array<struct< columnname:string,columnname1:int,columnname2:decimal(10,0),
columnname3:decimal(9,2)>>
```

What I tried so far:

```
import re
str=input("enter any string:")
fields=str.split(",")
for x in fields:
  name=x.split(":")
  seminame=name[0]+','
  firstname=seminame.find('`')
  lastname=seminame.rfind('`')
  fullname=seminame[(firstname+1):lastname]
  replacename1=fullname.replace(')', '')
  replacename2=fullname.replace('2', '')
  replacename3=fullname.replace('9', '')
  replacename4=fullname.replace('10', '')
  replacename5=fullname.replace('0', '')
  finalname='.'+replacename5
  print(finalname)
```

---

```
Input:
'`col` array<struct< columnname:string,columnname1:int,columnname2:decimal(10,0),
columnname3:decimal(9,2)>>'
```

I want the output as

```
Actual output
.col,
.columnname1,
.columnname2,
.),

Expected output
col.columnname,
col.columnname1,
col.columnname2,
col.columnname3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use re to do the same?

```
import re
str = "'`col` array<struct< columnname:string,columnname1:int,columnname2:decimal(10,0),columnname3:decimal(9,2)>>'"
word = re.findall("`\w+`",str,) # match for columns 
word = " ".join(word)
word = re.sub(r'\W+', '', word) # strip `` 
columnnames = re.findall(r"(\w+):",str) # find all words before `:`
for c in columnnames:
  c = re.sub(r'\W+', '', c) # to remove `:`
  print  "%s.%s," %( word,c)
```

Output :

```
col.columnname,
col.columnname1,
col.columnname2,
col.columnname3,
```

To read from file you can use `open(filename,mode)` method

```
import re
with open("test.txt","r") as h:
 str = h.read()
 word = re.findall(r"`\w+`",str,)
 word = " ".join(word)
 word = re.sub(r'\W+', '', word)
 columnnames = re.findall(r"(\w+):",str)
 for c in columnnames:
    c = re.sub(r'\W+', '', c)
    print  "%s.%s," %( word,c)
```

To Write to File:

```
import re
with open("test.txt","r") as h:
with open("output.dat","a") as w:
str = h.read()
word = re.findall(r"`\w+`",str,)
word = " ".join(word)
word = re.sub(r'\W+', '', word)
columnnames = re.findall(r"(\w+):",str)
for c in columnnames:
    c = re.sub(r'\W+', '', c)
    data =  "%s.%s," %( word,c)
    w.write(data+"\n")
w.close()
h.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and providing solution. how to enter input values?

Comment: I am getting error in  line 2 "TypeError: expected string or buffer"

Comment: It is working as expected. But I want to read the input from  a file.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you.How to write the results  into file. I also try it from my end. If you got time let me know How to write the results  into file

Comment: You can use `handler.write(string)` method . Updated the answer . Please Check

Comment: removed w.close()
h.close() and it is working fine.Thank you for your help your  awesome

Comment: Ah. Sorry Wrong indentation. Happy to help :)